# Is there an alternative way to close stdin file descriptor (currently using <&- with shell=True)?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I would like to write a python script that interacts with dmenu. I was able to figure out that if I want dmenu to take user input only, I can pass

```
dmenu <&-
```

and it will display a clean user input prompt. I know the equivalent way of doing that in python using subprocess is

```
subprocess.check_output("dmenu <&-", shell=True)
```

However I don't think this is the best way, since if I am using a prompt, it will interpret the prompt text as bash syntax (for instance in "dmenu -p 'Project?'" it will interpret the '?').

Is there a way to use subprocess.Popen to achieve the same? I tried a whole bunch of different stuff such as

```
subprocess.Popen("dmenu", stdin=None)
```

```
import sys
sys.stdin.close()
subprocess.Popen("dmenu", stdin=sys.stdin)
```

Is using shell=True the only way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. But what exactly does `<&-` do ?

Comment: I read that it duplicates the file descriptor (standard input here). Here doing `sys.stdin.close()` then using that for `Popen` isn't going to cut it obviously

Comment: It closes stdin I believe. I found the example on a forum. Here is better info from [https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: `<&-` does indeed close fd 0. You could call `os.close(0)` in a `preexec_fn`, but using `<&-` is not a good idea in the first place—better to use `</dev/null`, which will point you to using `subprocess.DEVNULL` here, which is the best way as long as your subprocess has `subprocess.DEVNULL` (3.3 or later). The `input=b''` method is the second-best way.

Comment: oh that is true. For some reason I didn't see `check_output` also has `stdin` as arg in addition to `input`. So something like `subprocess.check_output("dmenu", stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)` also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is provide no input to dmenu, so:

```
subprocess.check_output("dmenu", input=b"")
```

Comment: oh that is pretty simple, thanks! I guess even **echo "" | dmenu** works ok, rather than **dmenu <&-**